# Remove specific char with regex

Tags: c#, regex

I have diffrent string pattern as below

```
Foo MU16
Foo WU14
```

etc.

I would like to get as below result

```
Foo U16
Foo U14
```

I am trying to remove as below codes but I am not getting right result

```
(?<=\bmu)u(?=\d),""
```

Comment: I am using regex with C#

Comment: why you are using `(?<=\bmu)u(?=\d`? It will require the letters `mu` to be present before an `u` (`Foo MUU16` for example), and the pattern shows that before the `u` there is just one letter (not specifically `m`). **SWLim** suggestion seems a beeter choice, or maybe `(?<=\b\w)u(?=\d)`, or something even better if you could add any detail that shows if the pattern does not really fit in any of the already suggested regular expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your pattern is always like the example you have given, then the following should work:

`\b\w(?=U\d)`

Explanation:
Select at word boundary `\b` which follows by a single word character `\w` , which has a lookahead `(?=`) of the character `U` that follows with a digit `\d`.

Comment: I am changing string to lower case before using regex

Comment: Extra: In case you have no use of the lower case'd string aside from replacing with regex, then I suppose using the case-insensitive flag would be a good idea :)

Comment: If the pattern is always like the example, then you could also just remove the 5th character. Or just match `[MW]`. We need more information about the actual strings OP needs to work with :|

Comment: You have raised a good point. We shall wait and see what the OP's actual requirement is.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help

Comment: @Kerberos Is the string always going to be in that format? If yes, then what Blorgbeard has suggested would be a much solution.